# is there any way to configure waf to build c++ program in mac os?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, waf

I just suffer a problem that the all the things works well on my ubuntu. 
However, I want to get things work on my mac, bad thing happens. 
it shows the following errors

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"
```

I am total new to mac stuff, I got the xcode 4 installed. 
I guess there must be c++0x, but I wonder how can i configure it with waf.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: "I just suffer a problem that the all the things works well on my ubuntu". hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m guessing you’re using GCC supplied with Xcode. That’d be GCC 4.2.1, a rather old version that won’t be updated by Apple in the foreseeable future.

You have essentially two options:

- Xcode ships Clang/LLVM besides GCC, so you could use Clang/LLVM instead. That `-std=c++0x` option is recognised by Clang/LLVM but C++0x is not as fully supported as in recent versions of GCC. [The LLVM project keeps a page listing their current C++0x support status](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).
- Use a more recent version of GCC. You can either compile it locally or install it via one the open source package managers available on Mac OS X: MacPorts, Fink, Homebrew. I don’t really know if and which versions of GCC they’re able to build, so check with them first.

Comment: Also, it could be the case that waf itself is already available in those package managers.

Answer (score 2):

As **Xcode** comes with **Clang** on mac you can get **c++0x** support if you configure **waf** to use **Clang**.

In your `wscript` add to configure:

```
def configure( conf ):
    ...
    conf.env.CXXFLAGS = [ '-std=c++0x', '-stdlib=libc++' ]
    conf.env.LINKFLAGS = [ '-std=c++0x', '-stdlib=libc++' ]
    ....
```

Then run **waf** as:

```
CXX=clang++ waf configure
CXX=clang++ waf build
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac you can't go wrong with [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/).  You'll have to build the compiler yourself (using e.g. gcc-4.2 that you already have).  It has -std=c++0x.  The support for it isn't complete, but it is growing all the time.  On the Mac you might also look at [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) for C++0x support (combined with clang).